# Why does bidimensional char array behave this way in C?

Tags: arrays, c, char, printf, string-literals

Recently I came back to the C language and decided that HackerRank would be good to begin with.
There is this problem : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/for-loop-in-c.

I tried this :

```
int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);
    char rep[9][5] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        if(i <= 9 && i >= 1)
        {
            printf("%s\n", rep[i - 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf((i % 2 == 0) ? "even\n" : "odd\n"); 
        }     
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and got this output:

```
eightnine
nine
even
odd
```

I know that the preffered way to do this is to use the const char * array, but shouldn't this work too? Why does it print an extra "nine"?

Comment: `"eight"` isn't a `char[5]`, but a `char[6]`, including a zero terminator.

Comment: C++ is not C, don't spam tags. These so called competitive programming sites are terrible places to learn to code, you should seek better resources.

Comment: "*I know that the preffered way to do this is to use the const char * array*" -- maybe.  It depends on multiple factors.  In any case, your second dimension, 5, is not large enough to accommodate a string terminator for some of your strings.

Comment: `char rep[9][5] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};`  should be `char rep[9][6] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};` the comments above explain why.

Comment: @PasserBy womp womp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string literal like that `"three"` contains 6 characaters including the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

So you need to declare the array `rep` at least like

```
char rep[9][6] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
```

Otherwise the conversion specifier `%s` used in this call of `printf`

```
printf("%s\n", rep[i - 1]);
```

will try to output all characters until the terminating zero character `'\0'` will be encountered.

Though it would be better to declare the array like

```
const char *rep[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
size_t N = sizeof( rep ) / sizeof( *rep );
```

In the if statement of the for loop you can write

```
    if( 1 <= i && i <= N )
```

Pay attention to that in C++ the compiler will issue an error message because the declaration

```
char rep[9][5] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
```

is invalid in C++.

C++ does not allow to ignore the terminating zero character of string literals used as initializers of character aarrays.